# Two Minim in the Extra Mishloach Manos

Tags: mishloach-manot

If one is giving more than one Mishloach Manos are they still הרי זו משובח if the extra ones do not have 2 minim?

As is written in Shulchan Aruch 695:4 וכל המרבה לשלוח לרעים משבח

Comment: Why would it be Meshubach if there was 2 minim?

Comment: Please edit your post for grammar. When you add information, there's no need to append it at the end in a sentence fragment. Write it as if you were writing it from the outset: full sentences, ordered logical flow, background, translation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rav Ovadia Yosef writes in Chazon Ovadia Purim (pg 133) that if on wants to give subsequent "praiseworthy" Mishloach Manot, one does not need to follow all the halachic details, such as the requirement for two manot, for any subsequent Mishloach Manot. He cites Yosef Ometz (Yuzpeh) who also has this opinion and disagrees with Torat Avidgor who writes that even the subsequent Mishloach Manot must have two manot.